# Getting android_key_not_configured facebook error

Tags: android, facebook, android-emulator

I am trying to enable facebook login in my android app. I have linked the the facebook app in my application. But once i press login, then I get the facebook error **android_key_not_configured**

Has any body seen this before?

Comment: did you registered and put your own application key?

Comment: I have app_ID of the application, I also signed the application via debug key

Answer (score 2):

I saw this message too. I hadn't added a key in the `"Key Hashes"` field on the `Facebook Native Android App menu`. I went ahead and added a dummy key "foo". After adding this dummy key, the next time I ran the app, after waiting about 5 minutes, I got

> "Login failed" invalid_key:Android key mismatch. Your key "MY_KEY"
>   does match the allowed keys specified in your application settings.